# How to solve the ENGINE = InnoDB' error in SQL?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to add a table 'users' in a database 'restoratedb'. So, using the following code gives me an error message

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `restoratedb`.`users` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`user_id` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I'm getting the bellow error message

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')
ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 14
```

Comment: Either you are using an old version of MySQL or there's a syntax problem you are not showing. It works well in the fiddle. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p2wYCW1sVABZLUPKnncJ3t/0

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return?

Comment: @BillKarwin 10.4.24-MariaDB

Comment: It's the keyword [VISIBLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/) which is not known in MariaDB, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=6a0f39105d401207ec1c518f34db284b)